# How to make PM2 as a autostart service?

Tags: linux

I want to make my PM2 as a startup service, because for example when my server loses power or something happens to it, it does not automatically restart the PM2 service.

Answer (score 2):

When configuring PM2 is finished and it's working properly, you must run two commands to make your PM2 as a autostart service and enjoy that.
1) Run 'pm2 save': It's save all of your PM2 configure to a file.

```
admin@server:~$ sudo pm2 save
```

2) Run 'pm2 startup': This command creates a system service and runs your last change saved with the first step.

```
admin@server:~$ sudo pm2 startup
```

So, Run the first command when you changed the configuration to store the last changes.